# How to get value from object Json.deserialize

Tags: apex, json, map, object

I have deserialized a JSON object as follows:

```
MyObjects MyA = (MyObjects) JSON.deserialize(req.requestBody.toString(),MyObjects.class);
```

When I do MyA.get('Accounts') my result is as follows

```
({AccountType=null, Addresses=null, Code=cd12345, Contacts=null, CreatedDate=null, CustomValues=null, Id=12345, ModifiedDate=null, Name=null, Relationships=null, ...})
```

How do I get the value for Code?

Comment: As usual, it's a lot harder to include too many details than too few. Including too few details makes it harder to answer questions. It'll help if you include the code for your `MyObjects` class. The answer is probably along the lines of "the same way you access any other value in any other class", but the specifics depend on the class you're using to deserialize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you please elaborate a little more your question please.

In addition what I understand is that you need to get the value of a field of the object, maybe you should try to access directly.

```
MyObjects MyA = (MyObjects) JSON.deserialize(req.requestBody.toString(),MyObjects.class);
String code = MyA.Code;
```

Because when you de-serialize what you are actually doing is constructing an object from the JSON string (req.requestBody.toString()) through the de-serialize method indicating the structure of the object (MyObjects.class).

---

Also I recommend this links.

[JSON Class Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm)

[How can I read JSON value of field?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/161536/how-can-i-read-json-value-of-field)